# How to get container id of running container programmatically (on Docker)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an app in a docker setup. I would like to run a script on the host that would run some commands in an existing (running container).

If I know the container id, say ... it's 50250e572090 ... then I can run the script like this

For example ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker exec 50250e572090 example_command_1_here
docker exec 50250e572090 example_command_2_here
docker exec 50250e572090 example_command_3_here
docker exec 50250e572090 example_command_4_here
```

It's working great! ... but the thing here is that I only know the image name ... not the container id. To find the container id ... I use `docker ps` ... where I get something like this ...

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
50250e572090        aws_beanstalk/staging-app:latest   "/sbin/my_init"     29 hours ago        Up 29 hours         80/tcp, 443/tcp     drunk_bardeen
```

It's output isn't something that I can use (pipe through). Which command can I run to get the container id as the output which can then be piped into the script? Or now that it's clear what I'm trying to achieve ... is there a better way?

Ps: My context is that I'm on elastic beanstalk ... but I don't see how this changes anything. Might as well be on the local host ... the problem is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this using the `-q` flag. Like so ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker exec `docker ps -q` example_command_1_here
docker exec `docker ps -q` example_command_2_here
docker exec `docker ps -q` example_command_3_here
docker exec `docker ps -q` example_command_4_here
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're requesting is not that easy. Multiple containers can use the same image.

You can use `docker ps` with a filter to only see containers derived from a specific image:

```
$ docker ps -q --filter "ancestor=aws_beanstalk/staging-app:latest"
```

Please note that this will return all running containers using the `aws_beanstalk/staging-app:latest` image which might be *more* than one.

Answer (score 0):

You can run docker inspect command and get the Id of the container;

```
viswesn@viswesn-PC1:~$ docker inspect My_First_Docker | grep Id | awk '{print $2}'
"e3824f0121f24dded9792f133344a2d68b46ea13065481c30caf35d0ac6be40e",
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I wanted a better answer than was given here, and I figured it out:

```
docker ps -q --no-trunc --format="{{.ID}}" --filter "ancestor=image/repo/and:tag"
```

You can leave off `:tag` if you want, or you can filter on something else entirely. The output will be the full, un-truncated ID of each matching container. No column headers or anything else extraneous.

If you only need the short version (first twelve hex digits) of the ID, leave off `--no-trunc`.